# With Steams graphics "auto updater" for ATI Radeon, can I just have the drivers?

Tags: steam, graphics-card

Steam, the other day, offered to keep my drivers for my ATI Radeon card up to date. I thought that's not a bad idea because the number of updates I get can be a bit annoying, so I'm fine to let Steam do it for me.

I let it download and install, and now I'm the not-so-proud owner of the ATI Vision Engine Control Center, something I despise due to the extra crud and bloatware that comes with it. Can I ask Steam to install just the drivers and leave the extra stuff alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open `Control Panel`, and there the `Programs and Features`
- Find `AMD Catalyst Install Manager`. Click on "Change".
- Choose `Uninstall Manager` from the list.

Uncheck `AMD Catalyst Control Center`, and finish the uninstall process. You probably won't have to restart the computer, but do it, if required.

[Here](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/GPU57RemoveOldGraphicsDrivers.aspx#windows7) you can find a how-to describing a complete uninstall, which you might as well choose.

Answer (score 2):

Not worth it really. Just download the Drivers from ATI's site and choose what you want to install. It's always better to have more control when you install drivers etc

Comment: If you do this, make sure to choose the clean install option if available. Sometimes, an update that's not cleanly installed may have options or settings poorly transitioned leading to system instability. The week before the Windows 10 Creator update was released, I had to clean install my drivers because Windows Update installed the drivers for me and botched the update. I can imagine Steam or a poorly configured update may do the same thing.